# Missing manpage for `ifconfig`

Tags: ifconfig, manpage

```
$ man ifconfig
No manual entry for ifconfig
See 'man 7 undocumented' for help when manual pages are not available.

$ dpkg -l | grep -i manpages
ii  manpages                            3.54-1ubuntu1                all          Manual pages about using a GNU/Linux system
ii  manpages-dev                        3.54-1ubuntu1                all          Manual pages about using GNU/Linux for development
ii  manpages-posix                      2.16-1                       all          Manual pages about using POSIX system
ii  manpages-posix-dev                  2.16-1                       all          Manual pages about using a POSIX system for development
```

How do I get the ifconfig manpage installed on Ubuntu 13.10?

Comment: For Ubuntu 13.10, the ifconfig man page is part of [the net-tools package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/amd64/net-tools/filelist) and should be installed at `/usr/share/man/man8/ifconfig.8.gz`.  Check to see if that file is there.

Comment: Thanks. I got this resolved by re-installing the "net-tools" package. I can't answer my own question since my reputation is too low.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem has been resolved by re-installing the "net-tools" package. The possible cause of such issue might be a skewed previous installation.

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall net-tools
```

P.S.: At the time during my research for solutions on this issue, I found that I need to know which package the command belongs to. Here is how you do it:

```
$ dpkg -S `which ifconfig`
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the man for other commands. If you face the same problem with all the commands then the reason is that the $MANPATH might not be correctly set.

Please set the $MANPATH by

```
export $MANPATH=/path/to/man
```

For example:

```
export $MANPATH=/usr/local/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man
```